# Cannot see macOS volumes in Boot Camp

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, disk-volume

I upgraded from a MacBook Pro with Windows 7 in Boot Camp to an iMac with Windows 10 in Boot Camp.

In Windows 7 my I had read access to my macOS volumes (no write access), however, in Windows 10 I can only see the Windows Boot Camp volume in Windows Explorer.

Are the Mac volumes no longer accessible from within Windows?

Answer (score 1):

APFS volumes cannot be read in Windows. Boot Camp only provides drivers for HFS+ volumes, so it's not a problem with the version of Windows but rather that the format of the Mac volume has moved on beyond the support drivers made available by Apple for Boot Camp.

Comment: I assume the use of APFS is optional. If so, then I assume this problem could be fixed by reinstalling macOS to partitions that do not use APFS?